# Is it implied in the question that $x$ is greater than $-1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, area

> Let $f(x)=$minimum $(x+1,\sqrt{1-x})$ for all $x\le1$. Find the area bounded by $y=f(x)$ and the x-axis.

The answer given is $\int_{-1}^0(x+1)dx+\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x}dx$

I wonder why we are starting from $x=-1$.

Is it implied in the question that $f(x)$ is positive?

Comment: Have you plotted the function? Which area is bounded by that function and the $x$ axis?

Comment: _'Find the area bounded by'_ means the figure _between_ the $f$ graph and the $X$ axis. So you need to identify a subset of the domain, in which $f$ is bounded and constant sign. That implies limits of integration.

Comment: Ok, area for $x$ less than $-1$ is unbounded. Sorry for the silly question.